# Regresar valor original sin condición no se cumple pandas

Tags: pandas, condiciones, texto, criteria

Tengo un df que tiene una columna que contiene una serie de textos que unos están bien otros necesitan ser modificados.  He tratado varias cosas:

Método 1:

```
def criteria(row):
if row.Municipio.find ('Quetzaltenago')>=0:
    return 'Quetzaltenango'
if row.Municipio.find ('Quetzalteanango')>=0:
    return 'Quetzaltenango'
else:
    return row
```

Funcionó, pero cuando se exporta a excel, no sale el sólo el nombre de la fila sino sale todo esto, cuando debería ser sólo Guatemala
**Municipio    Guatemala
Name: 1, dtype: object**

Método 2:

```
df1['Municipio'] = df1.apply(lambda x: 'Quetzaltenango' if x == 'Quetzaltenago' else x)
```

aplicando lo encontrado en:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61368876/how-to-return-the-original-value-in-a-apply-function

Error:  The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

¿Cómo puedo usar cualquiera de las dos?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

La respuesta corta es que en tu segúndo método estas haciendo `df1.apply` y lo que necesitas hacer es `df1['Municipio'].apply`

```
df1['Municipio'] = df1['Municipio'].apply(lambda x: 'Quetzaltenango' if x == 'Quetzaltenago' else x)
```

La respuesta un poco más larga es que en realidad lo que necesitas es tener más de una condición (Supongo que por eso optaste por un `if` como primera opción) así que lo que podrías hacer es un diccionario con todas las variantes de las palabras que te gustaría corregir

Por ejemplo:

```
d = {'Quetzaltenago': 'Quetzaltenango', 'Quetzalteanango': 'Quetzaltenango'}
```

Y luego reemplazar todas las coincidencias al mismo tiempo con [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
df = df.replace(d)
```

Cree un ejemplo sencillo con un pequeño `dataframe` de la siguiente forma (En el archivo sample.csv)

```
    Municipio
0   Quetzaltenango
1   Quetzaltenago
2   Quetzalteanango
3   Guatemala
```

Aplicando los comentarios anteriores

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Quetzaltenago': 'Quetzaltenango', 'Quetzalteanango': 'Quetzaltenango'}

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df = df.replace(d)
```

Al imprimir `df` devuelve:

```
    Municipio
0   Quetzaltenango
1   Quetzaltenango
2   Quetzaltenango
3   Guatemala
```

De esta forma podrías corregir todas las palabras mal escritas en cualquier parte (Fila o columna) de tu `dataframe`